# Memory issue with ViewPager

Tags: java, android, memory, android-viewpager

I'm currently developing an app that uses a ViewPager, the problem is that the way I'm doing it makes it extremely slow to start and takes up tonnes of memory.

I'm implementing the pageradapter like so:

```
        public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        views = new ArrayList<RelativeLayout>();
        views.add(new SliderLayout(context, "slide 8"));
        views.add(new SliderLayout(context, "slide 1"));
        views.add(new SliderLayout(context, "slide 2"));
        views.add(new SliderLayout(context, "slide 3"));
        views.add(new SliderLayout(context, "slide 4"));
        views.add(new SliderLayout(context, "slide 5"));
        views.add(new SliderLayout(context, "slide 6"));
        views.add(new SliderLayout(context, "slide 7"));
        views.add(new SliderLayout(context, "slide 8"));
        views.add(new SliderLayout(context, "Slide 1"));
    }
```

All the layoutobjects contain a FrameLayout with a textView and a [panel](http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/source/browse/trunk/android-misc-widgets/src/org/miscwidgets/widget/Panel.javamisc-widgets/) that contains a webview with local html. All the layouts have unique content, that is loaded and inflated when the SliderLayout class is instantiated.

I also attempted to add views on the fly in the instantiateItem method, but that just makes the scrolling more dodgy and will give an OutOfMemory fatal exception if I scroll too fast.

So my question is, what is the best way to implement a ViewPager that contains several unique views (but based on the same layout), so it doesn't consume so much memory and starts quicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must attach your views to pager in instantiateItem() (like you do it in regular adapter's getView() method). In this case ViewPager takes care about memory management. Take a look into demo project in CompatibilityPackage. Actually you can have thousands of pages without any lags.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    View v = layoutInflater.inflate(...);
    ...
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v,0);
    return tv;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((TextView) view);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, which demo-project are you referring to? I can't seem to find anything specific, that would help me with my original question.

Comment: Look at FragmentPagerSupport.java in Support4Demos folder. There is ViewPager with fragments, but you can use PagerAdapter instead of FragmetPagerAdapter and replace getItem(int position) method to public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int pos) method (like you do this with regular ListView's adapters). Sorry, my bad, I get you wrong method name early.

Answer (score 0):

hm, my idea is to catch the event "onPageChanged()" in the ViewPager and set the
webview after the page has changed - or, to preload as example a page so you have
the "scroll effect": you do the following:

as example, you have a count of 10 pages. if your viewpager is at page 0, then you instanciate and load the pages 0,1,2. if your viewpager is at screen 4, then you remove the webviews
at positions 0,1 and 7,8,9...

in this way you dont need all instances of webviews (webkit consumes a lot of memory)
and have some more memory.

Comment: I'm not sure that's it, since it still uses a LOT of memory if I disable all webviews..

Comment: ViewPager myViewPager = "...find the instance here..."
    myViewPager.removeView(myWebkitView);

In this way you make sure the webkit instance isnt in the pagetree from ViewPager object.

Comment: thank you, but I tried removing ALL webviews, from all the layouts and it still uses almost the same amount of memory. I'm guessing it's in the way that all the layouts are inflated at the same time or something to that extent..