# How to smooth mobile UX in switching between different pages?

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile

***Background:***

A few mobile pages reside in an app, we are after a UX that takes 0 second for user to switch from one page to another

***Method #1***:  Having multiple web views in app

Concern: Risk in App Crash due to increase in memory consumption
Pros: Effort is low per reuse of current code base

***Method #2*** : building native pages in app from scratch

Concern: Effort might be high, for one single UX, customization might need to be implemented for each major device, e.g., IPhone, IPad, Android Phones, Android Pads

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can use a ViewPager with fragments. You can force the fragments to load all at once or you can Load them as the user swipes. Fragments usually cache a few views in memory also so if the users swipes back that page will be automatically loaded.

If you use an [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html), android will take care of the memory management for you and reuse as much as possible. Take a look to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832322/memory-issue-with-viewpager) about ViewPager memory management.

Comment: Thanks so much, let me try your suggestion from my end, meanwhile I'm also after this UX on IOS as well, kindly please feel free to share.